# SQL statement SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, sql, derby

I'm getting an error executing the following SQL statement:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE RESERVATION (";
sql = sql + " UID VARCHAR,";
sql = sql + " ISBN INTEGER,";
sql = sql + " DATEISSUE DATE,";
sql = sql + " DATERETURN DATE,";
sql = sql + " FOREIGN KEY (UID) REFERENCES USERS (UID),";
sql = sql + " FOREIGN KEY (ISBN) REFERENCES BOOKS (ISBN) )";
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "," at
>   line 1, column 39.

Comment: `VARCHAR(SIZE)` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column 39 is near the end of the `varchar`, so  you probably need a size for it, such as `varchar(20)`.

Comment: Thanks i was ignoring that and looking at different thins Thanks.